# Is South Park episode 11x3 based on any sci fi film?

Tags: story-identification

The plot of the show shows all the kids in the 4th grade getting head lice.

There's a subplot of the show where the lice on Clyde's have developed into a thriving culture and they discover their world is alive and conscious. It seems like this was derived from some film or book.

Am I right? Is this episode derived from some past movie?

Comment: I also assumed I must be missing some reference when I saw that episode.

Comment: It is none of the above! The whole plot of the lice planet is taken from an animated movie, unfortunately I can't remember its name. Their planet was dying and and had something about moving to the forbidden zone through upside down trees.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling the episode based directly on a scifi book or movie is bit of a stretch.

The episode does have numerous cameos and references to popular scifi elements. To name a few :

- The Cartman headlice test closely resembles the tests done in [The Thing
  (1982)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_%281982_film%29)
- All the talk about "The forbidden zone" might be linked to
  [The old space hunter flicks (1983)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086346/) fanned by Trey Parker, the
  writer of the episode. Could also be a reference to Planet of the
  Apes where a similar desolate area exists beyond civilization.
- The scene where a louse argues with the Vice President is similar to a
  scene with Dennis Quaid from The Day After Tomorrow.
- The scene featuring lice running through a "forest" of hair is a reference to Apocalypto.

There are even references to Lord of the Rings in there as well.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of possible influences.

There's an SF story which I can't track down at the moment where a man has an abscess on his tooth, but delays going to the dentist, in which time it evolves into a complex intelligent society.

The other one that springs to mind is Greg Bear's story Blood Music (later expanded into a novel of the same name) where a scientist infects himself with microscopic intelligent computers which quickly develop into a civilization, taking over first his own body and then the rest of humanity's.

Comment: The concept vaugely also parallels The Simpsons Treehouse of Horror VII: The Genesis Tub where Lisa's tooth left in soda becomes it's own society. I searched for the inspiration for that episode but couldn't find one; must have been too silly to even be a Twilight Zone story.

Comment: The inspiration for The Genesis Tub was indeed a Twilight Zone story: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_People

Comment: I think *The Genesis Tub* was mentioned in another *South Park* episode, possibly called *The Simpsons Already Did It*.

Answer (score -1):

When I saw the episode, it reminded me of [The Carpet People](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Carpet_People) by Terry Pratchett.